# Empty story clicks statistics in Facebook application insights

Tags: php, facebook, analytics, facebook-insights

Posting stories via php facebook application using such construction :

```
$facebook->api('/'.$wall_id.'/feed',
          'post',
          array(
              'access_token' => $access_token, 
              'message' => $message,
              'picture' => $picture,
              'caption' => $caption,
              'link' => $link
              )
      );
```

There are "**702 Stories Published**" in app insights ( Apps->My application->Insights->Stream Publish ). But there are no Story Impressions or Story Clicks at all. (702 - 0 - 0)

Is it a bug, or do I need to pass some additional parameters to FB api to track these clicks?

Answer (score 0):

How much time has passed since the stories have been first posted? Facebook Insights requires at least three days to update its data.

Let's wait, and we'll see if this is a bug. I don't know about any special parameter to enable tracking: it should be available without any configuration.

Comment: This app is running since May,31. Think that 10 days is quite enough to show stats of first stories.

Comment: Here is images of users stats - http://imgur.com/QkjItoq,3Yq1i4Z#0. 914 new users and second - http://imgur.com/QkjItoq,3Yq1i4Z#1 702 stories and 0 clicks

Comment: Yes, it is quite enough. :) I think it is a bug, or maybe someone does know a solution.